# Schedule Quartz job and run in startup

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I defined a job with Quartz that calls a web service. I have a trigger with Cron expression which run every 50 minutes as `0 0/50 * ? * * *` .
I have a requirement that execute the job in startup application and after that every 50 minutes.

the job factory is:

```
            Trigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity(name, "our.trigger")
                                          .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 
                                              0/50 * ? * * *")).startNow().build();
            JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(jobClass).withIdentity(name, "our.job").build();
            Set<Trigger> triggers = new HashSet<>();
            triggers.add(trigger);
            stdScheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, triggers, true);
            stdScheduler.start();
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: i think you have to add  a second SimpleTrigger with startNow(), because startNow on Cron trigger has no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following code:

```
 Trigger startupTrigger = newTrigger().withIdentity(name+".startup", "trigger")
                            .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatSecondlyForTotalCount(1)).startNow().build();
```

Thanks for @biiyamn